# OpenGL near clipping messed up

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a plane that gets clipped when it gets too close. However, I can see that there is definately more space for the plane to expand. Here's an example of what I'm seeing

[image]

The entire thing is a gaitn square, but the part closest to the screen has been cut off. It seems to happen only when I bring the "camera" down. I know that in games it is possible to have the camera very low and still render everything close to the screen, so I can't understand why it's not working here

Comment: You should definitely add more information. For example: Which version of OpenGL do you use ? If older version, do you use immediate mode ? Give us code of your shaders (if you have any custom shader code). Also information about you view frustum parameters would help. Do you do any matrix multiplication on CPU ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a line like this somewhere?

```
GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f,(float)Display.getWidth()/(float)Display.getHeight(),0.1f,300.0f);
```

This could be your problem. The first term is the FOV in degrees, the second is the screen aspect ratio, the third and fourth are the depth of view. If the third value is not zero you will not see things that are too close to you.